# Sleep mode consumes as much as battery as when laptop is in use

Tags: suspend, power-management, lenovo

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 on a Lenovo X1 Carbon 6th gen. When closing the lid or putting the laptop to sleep manually, I notice that the battery drains as fast as when I'm using it. The laptop gets hot if I transport it in a sleeve during sleep. Both the power button and the ThinkPad red LED at the back of the screen are blinking, indicating that the suspend mode is activated.

Any advice in making the sleep mode more efficient? I don't want to shutdown and restart my computer every time I need to transport it.

Comment: It sounds like it is not sleeping at all but still turned on with the lid closed. This is the default dir some installs so the can works with external monitor and keyboard with lid closed.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, OP said that "power button and the ThinkPad red LED at the back of the screen are blinking". They don't do that when you have configured the machine to not do anything when the lid is closed, which I have.

Comment: @RainerBlome The fact it overheats inside the laptop bag and the battery dies hints it isn't sleeping / suspended.  You could be right and it really is asleep / suspended.

Comment: I have the a similar issue on a Lenovo T460s, only within the last 6 months I started noticing this issue. Unlike OP my laptop however does not overheat while in sleep mode, the power does run out. I'm on 16.04 as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I could solve the issue. I will answer my own question hoping it helps anyone else facing the same problem.

The Lenovo X1 Carbon 6th gen uses a new sleeping state (Si03, Windows Modern Standby) instead of the traditional S3 sleep state. Linux does not support that new state.

The workaround presented here worked well: https://delta-xi.net/#056

Comment: Please write the work around. Just the link is not a good answer if the link goes dead.

Comment: You could bring this up with Ubuntu. Searching their issue tracker for "Si03" (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu?field.searchtext=si03) gives no result.

Comment: Wow, did that work for you?  Although a simple patch, that level of intrusion looks rather involved for most ubuntu fixes.

Comment: In Ubuntu there are plenty of workarounds out there as there should be since Linux is superiour technology. I am now on Win10 for months for work reasons and I can report that no mode of standby works with Microsoft Windows after you wipe the factory installed Windows. So without Lenovo special magic infusion into Windows, Modern Standby is not working --at all--. As usual Microsoft delivers inferiour product. Microsoft even melted this guys Display: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/X1-Carbon-6th-Gen-will-not-stay-asleep/td-p/4123632/page/2

Comment: The patch in the link is dead, you may use the patch here https://gist.github.com/ahaggart/8f2ccf83fc725f2df6ab6299f9ab11a3

Answer (score 5):

Since UEFI version 1.30, the patch given in the accepted answer is no longer needed. To enable sleep mode under Linux with the latest BIOS, reboot your laptop and in the BIOS settings under "Config", change the "Sleep State" setting to "Linux" instead of "Windows 10".

[image: ThinkPad Setup screenshot]

https://delta-xi.net/blog/#056:

> Finally, with the newly released UEFI version 1.30, Lenovo officially
> added the ACPI S3 sleep state specifically for Linux systems as opt-in
> BIOS setting.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: E14 user here: My options were "Windows and Linux" and "Linux S3". Setting it to "Linux S3" automatically enabled `[s2idle] deep`. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

Execute manually:

```
systemctl suspend -i
```

In my T470s, for some reason, when closing the lid it's like is only powering the screen off, but not really suspending it, although a dmesg shows the kernel supports the correct Sx states.